# How to manage in-app purchases outside of the Microsoft Store?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store, windows-dev-center

These questions are related to Microsoft Store related API , C# and VS2022.

Q1.Can I manage in-app purchases outside of the Microsoft Store, meaning using my own payment-gateway like stripe.com ?  if yes are there any sample example or article on the same.

Q2. Can I implement in-app purchases with a custom price for each customer?  for few customers we might want to give some varying discount.   any sample example or article on the same?

Regards

Comment: Any updates about your issue?

Comment: Not really.. we are still thinking should we use stripe 3rd party or be with MSFT.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is about app store policies and not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I manage in-app purchases outside of the Microsoft Store, meaning using my own payment-gateway like stripe.com ?

Yes, based on the [Store policy 10.8 Financial Transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/store-policies#108-financial-transactions), Non-game in-app products made available on PC devices **may either use a secure third-party purchase API or the Microsoft Store in-product purchase API** for in-app purchases of digital items or services that are consumed or used within the product.

> if yes are there any sample example or article on the same.

**No**, there is no sample about using third-party purchase API. You need to check the document of these third-party purchase APIs.

> Can I implement in-app purchases with a custom price for each customer? for few customers we might want to give some varying discount. any sample example or article on the same?

If you are using third-party purchase APIs, then this will be an issue that you need to check the third-party purchase API document.

For Microsoft Store in-product purchase API, there is no such function that provides a custom price for every customer. What you could do is that having different add-ons with different prices in the Microsoft Store. Then for different customers, you show the different add-ons.